# Software for proving sum identites

Tags: combinatorics, computer-algebra-systems, sequences-and-series

Summations can really get complicated - esp. when you have convoluted n-fold summations with all kinds of different indices.

**My question:** Is there some software (or add-on) with which you can find and prove (complicated) summation identities?

Comment: Implementations of Gosper's algorithm and related work (e.g. Zeilberger's algorithm and Petkovšek's algorithm).

Comment: Mathematica does it reasonably well. If you derived one sum from the other, then evaluate the sums for a large amount of values should give you enough confidence that the 2 are equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fabrizio Caruso implemented "Gosper's and Zeilberger's algorithm for proving and finding indefinite and definite hypergeometric summation identities", as a free and open source package for use with [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/). You can get it [here](http://www.risc.jku.at/research/combinat/software/Zeilberger/index.php).